# Can the MySQL system database tables be converted to InnoDB?

Tags: mysql, innodb, myisam, mariadb

I've installed MySQL 5.5 recently.  I'm using `InnoDB` as the engine for all  my databases. I noticed that the `mysql` database default and all of it's tables (user, db, etc...) are  `MyISAM`.  Is there any reason they cannot / should not be `InnoDB`?   Does anyone know if MySQL requires the `mysql` db to be `MyISAM`?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Warning
Do not convert MySQL system tables in the mysql database from MyISAM to InnoDB tables! This is an unsupported operation. If you do this, MySQL does not restart until you restore the old system tables from a backup or re-generate them with the mysql_install_db script.

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/innodb-restrictions.html

Comment: Absolutely. It's probably a bad idea to mess around with any of the system tables directly.

Comment: Nice.  Good thing I asked :) Scary to think there is such a big way a user could easily shoot themselves in the foot.

Comment: with power comes responsibility :)