# Can MySQL system tables be converted to InnoDB in the latest versions?

Tags: mysql, innodb, mariadb

I know historically the **system** tables in Mysql (and MariaDB) are stored in MyISAM format. Converting them to InnoDB was unsupported and would [break the database.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12902829/can-the-mysql-system-database-tables-be-converted-to-innodb)

However, that was 4 years ago. More recently, in May 2014, the MySQL team announced plans to not only support InnoDB for system tables, but to [make InnoDB the default type](http://www.tocker.ca/2014/05/22/mysql-soon-to-store-system-tables-in-innodb.html) for system tables.

I haven't seen any major articles about this change, but I know my MariaDB 10.1 system tables are still in MyISAM format. Is InnoDB still unsupported for system tables, or is there a flag that can be set to enable support in the latest versions of MySQL and MariaDB?

Comment: worst case, set up a test server and try converting one of the mysql.* tables to innodb and see what blows up.

Comment: No, even in 5.7 tables in database mysql must be MyISAM. The work on this is still going on, but apparently it's too much to change.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what would be the gain of having system tables as InnoDB?

Comment: I suggest that the lack of an announcement is due to the difficulty.  Think of the bootstrapping, rollback, undo, crash safety, etc issues.  Perhaps 5.8 will switch to InnoDB.  Perhaps the first several minor releases will uncover serious flaws in the transition.

Answer (score -2):

I've switch engines on individual tables before and haven't had too much trouble. No loss of data or anything. However I did have some performance issues. I would suggest backing up before doing anything of course. You may be better off taking a dump of the data first, switching your table engines and then importing the data back (just to be on the safe side). As mentioned in the comments above, test environment first.

Comment: I think you're talking about regular tables. I was asking about the system tables that are built-in to the mysql installation.